# ASP.NET model binding fails for enums with MSGraphSDK v5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json-deserialization, microsoft-graph-sdks

Someone needs to send a JSON file to my ASP.NET webapp, representing a [Microsoft.Graph.Beta.Models.ImportedDeviceIdentity](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-beta-sdk-dotnet/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Graph/Generated/Models/ImportedDeviceIdentity.cs).

Here is my controller action:

```
 [Consumes("application/json")]
 public IActionResult HandleImportDeviceIdentity([FromBody] Microsoft.Graph.Beta.Models.ImportedDeviceIdentity importDeviceIdentity)
 {
     ...
     return Ok();
 }
```

I am using MSGraphSDKDotNet v5 with ASP.NET (.NET Core 7).

If I send a JSON file like this:

```
    {
        "importedDeviceIdentityType": "serialNumber",
        "importedDeviceIdentifier": "TEST9999",
        "description": "TEST999"
    }
```

...then my importDeviceIdentity object is not properly initialized (it is set to null).

But if I use the numeric value for the *importedDeviceIdentityType* Enum like:

```
    {
        "importedDeviceIdentityType": 2,
        "importedDeviceIdentifier": "TEST9999",
        "description": "TEST999"
    }
```

...all is working fine.

I wasn't able to understand why ASP.Net was unable to bind the Enum string representation to the integer value, even if the *ImportedDeviceIdentity* object inherits from IParsable.

I don't won't to write a custom JSON converter, nor I would like to use cheap solution, such as binding to a string and de-serializing using the object methods (CreateFromDiscriminatorValue and Co...)

Seems I lack something like [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))] on the Enum, but as the class was not defined by myself, I cannot do that.  There is also no "@odata.type" attribute on the payload my controller will receive (not sure if this is relevant).

How can I convert the string representation properly during the model binding step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, enums are serialized as numbers. To serialize enum names as strings, use the `JsonStringEnumConverter`.

Globally register it in Program.cs like below:

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddJsonOptions(opts =>
{
    var enumConverter = new JsonStringEnumConverter();
    opts.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(enumConverter);
});
```

Comment: Yes, this solution worked, thanks so much! I didn't know that I can set that globally.  Alternatively, I found another trick using a JsonDocument : https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/1708, but it isn't elegant, and is exactly what I wanted to avoid :-).  (Sorry I cannot upvote your hint since I am new on SO).

Comment: Hi @user10863484, if my answer help you, could you pls accept it as an answer? Refer to: [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/673311).